# Could not build Objective-C module '_SwiftUIKitOverlayShims'

Tags: swift4, xcode9

In the **Xcode8.3.3** project will not be a problem, but after upgrading to **xcode9**, the compiler has a problem!

Showing Recent Issues

CompileSwift normal arm64

```
/Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/modules/ScrollerRefresh/RefreshConst.swift
    cd /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift -frontend -c -filelist /var/folders/cz/jq8bwvds0j52yy2j0p7_2kf40000gn/T/sources-86be14 -primary-file /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/modules/ScrollerRefresh/RefreshConst.swift -target arm64-apple-ios8.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk -I /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/Pods/RongCloudIM/RongCloudIM -F /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/modules -F /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/modules/Live/IJKMediaPlayer -F /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -swift-version 4 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -D DEBUG -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/mtom-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/mtom-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/mtom-all-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/mtom-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/Pods/Headers/Public/RongCloudIM -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom -emit-module-doc-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst~partial.swiftdoc -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst.dia -import-objc-header /Users/leekexi/Documents/macsrc/mtom/mtom-bridging.h -pch-output-dir /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders -pch-disable-validation -Onone -module-name mtom -emit-module-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst~partial.swiftmodule -emit-dependencies-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst.d -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst.swiftdeps -o /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/mtom.build/Debug-iphoneos/mtom.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RefreshConst.o -index-store-path /Users/leekexi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/mtom-aecafhlecijtaebzvztitxjcabvr/Index/DataStore -index-system-modules

<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "UIKitOverlayShims.h"
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/shims/UIKitOverlayShims.h:24:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIFocusSystem'
  return [UIFocusSystem environment:environment containsEnvironment:otherEnvironment];
          ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module '_SwiftUIKitOverlayShims'
```

Comment: Please check https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84400

Comment: I've filed a radar about this issue: http://www.openradar.me/34601923

Comment: This is occurring for 10.3 simulators for me but not on 11.0 simulators

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This fix from [the mentioned forum thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84400#discussion-261859) fixed it for me: Just delete the offending code!

1. Open the file the error points to (`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/shims/UIKitOverlayShims.h` for most people).
2. Delete the method `_swift_UIKit_UIFocusEnvironmentContainsEnvironment`, plus the surrounding compiler directives.

I rebuilt after that just to be sure, but that might not be necessary.

This is definitely a workaround; hopefully this will be fixed in a future version of Xcode.

Comment: I just commented on one of the statements, but I do not know if there is any impact

Comment: I get this error with Xcode 9.1.  I silenced it by editing my module map/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/shims/module.modulemap to comment out the line header "UIKitOverlayShims.h"

Comment: This will actually get rid of the generic message and reveal the real underlying issues. In my case I had framework imports mixed in. 
@import and #import <Module/header.h> mixed in the same file that xcode did not like

Comment: @mrh.is I cannot edit the `UIKitOverlayShims.h` file

Comment: @lee I had to use a program other than Xcode. Then when you try to save, that program should prompt you for your admin password.

Comment: @mrh.is: could you tell me which program did you used to edit?(I used `TextWrangler` but couldn't save file).

Comment: @lee I used Sublime Text.

Answer (score 5):

For me on Xcode 9.0.1 the solution has been the typical engineer solution:

1. Clean the project
2. Erase DerivedData
3. Reboot computer

Comment: Helped me too - shouldn't be really surprised.

Comment: No need to reboot the computed. Cleaning and rebuilding should do it too, maybe restart Xcode. If that fails, I'd delete DrivedData and only if that fails too, I'd restart the computer.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, it seems that the reboot is necessary in some situations, like mine. I tried all versions of rebuilding, quitting xcode and deleting derivedData, nothing worked until I rebooted. My issue was with debugging in lldb, getting the shim errors.

Comment: I can't believe the reboot was required... thank you!