# Running Swift 4 code on Xcode 8.3 - issue with Xcode Snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am facing issues with XCode snapshot.
Actually I have Xcode 8.3.3, but I need to run Swift 4 project on it. Upgrading OSX and Xcode version is not an option for me.

I followed the accepted answer from here: [Is it possible to compile Swift 4 on Xcode 8.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884571/is-it-possible-to-compile-swift-4-on-xcode-8-x)

I downloaded Xcode snapshot (latest, 30th Dec release of toolchain) from https://swift.org/download/#snapshots

and made the required settings of toolchain. However, I am encountering a strange issue.

[image]

Again, to resolve this, I tried the accepted answer on link [Could not build Objective-C module '_SwiftUIKitOverlayShims'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317074/could-not-build-objective-c-module-swiftuikitoverlayshims)

however, even this does not seem to work. Please suggest where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is the reason you can't upgrade? Because, to be completely honest, your best option really is to upgrade Xcode.

Comment: My Mac has a 4GB RAM and it is already very slow. Upgrading it to High Sierra and installing Xcode 9.2 will kill it totally..! That is why Im desperately looking for a workaround

Comment: I assume this is just to try Swift 4 out as you will never be able to submit an app using this method.