# Missing required module '_SwiftUIKitOverlayShims'

Tags: ios, xcode

I have created a new project with **xcode** but have the following error:

`Missing required module '_SwiftUIKitOverlayShims'`

What should I do?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/41849335/3287355

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317074/could-not-build-objective-c-module-swiftuikitoverlayshims

Answer (score 0):

Try this process -

1. Press `"Cmd + Shift + K"` or `shift + cmd + alt + k` to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. Delete the cache Run `"rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"` in terminal
3. Open the project and `re-build` it